# Python wallet list function

Tags: python, list, currency

I have been trying to figure out this HW problem since Thursday for my CS 101 class.

I can get bits and pieces of the canAfford function, but is shows under the wrong columns and I can't get everything to come out entirely correct. Any help is appreciated.

```
def canAfford(wallet, amount):
    """ Returns True if the wallet has enough money for the amount"""
    pass
    # Add your code here

    """ 
    Logic for this function (You are free to use this as a guide if you want)
    sort the wallet from smallest to largest
    loop through the "coins" in the wallet while smallest coin < amount
        (pay with the smallest coins first until the smallest coin
        is larger than the amount left to pay)
        remove/pop the coin from the wallet (give to the cashier)
        subtract coin value from amount 
    if there is still an amount to remove from the wallet (amount > 0)
        (the smallest coin will be > amount)
        remove the smallest coin (give to cashier)
        determine what change the cashier will give back to add to your 
wallet
        let variable moneyToAdd = smallest coin - amount
        add coins to the wallet that represent moneyToAdd (refill your 
wallet)
    return the wallet
    """





def displayWallet(wallet):
    """ Displays the current coins in a wallet - Dont change """
    print('{:>10}{:>10}{:>10}{:>10}{:>10} : {:>5} 
cents'.format(wallet.count(1), 
                      wallet.count(5), wallet.count(10), 
wallet.count(25), 
                      wallet.count(100), sum(wallet)))
    pass
```

#===========================================================================
    # Main code - Don't change this code

```
# set wallet with 1 dollar
wallet = [100]

# Display headers for wallet change
print('{:>10}{:>10}{:>10}{:>10}{:>10} : {:>5}'.format('Cents', 
'Nickels', 'Dimes', 'Quarters', 'Dollars', 'total'))

displayWallet(wallet)

amountOfItem = 13
while (canAfford(wallet, amountOfItem)):
    wallet = buyItem(wallet, amountOfItem)
    displayWallet(wallet)

print('remaining wallet')
displayWallet(wallet)

"""
Instructions:
- You will implement a wallet as a Python list.
- This wallet will contain change.
- For this program:
     a penny will be represented as 1
     a nickel as 5
     a dime as 10, 
     a quarter as 25
     a dollar as 100
- You will be implementing the function buyItem() that will take the 
  current wallet and the purchase amount for an item.  You will
  make the correct change for the cost of the item with the
  change in the wallet.
- The program will continue to buy an item of 13 cents while there 
  is enough money in the wallet to purchase that item.
- Review how floor divide (//) and modulus (%) work with numbers.
Sample Output:
     Cents   Nickels     Dimes  Quarters   Dollars : total
         0         0         0         0         1 :   100 cents
         2         0         1         3         0 :    87 cents
         4         0         2         2         0 :    74 cents
         1         0         1         2         0 :    61 cents
         3         0         2         1         0 :    48 cents
         0         0         1         1         0 :    35 cents
         2         0         2         0         0 :    22 cents
         4         1         0         0         0 :     9 cents
remaining wallet
         4         1         0         0         0 :     9 cents
"""
```

here is all I can get so far

```
Sample Output:
     Cents   Nickels     Dimes  Quarters   Dollars : total
         0         0         0         0         0 :   100 cents
         0         2         0         1         3 :    87 cents
         0         4         0         2         2 :    74 cents
         0         1         0         1         2 :    61 cents
         0         3         0         2         1 :    48 cents
         0         0         0         1         1 :    35 cents
         0         2         0         2         0 :    22 cents
         0         4         1         0         0 :     9 cents
remaining wallet
         0         0         0         0         0 :   100 cents
```

Comment: What do you expect the output to be, and what did you actually get?

Comment: I'm wondering why the comments suggest paying with the smallest coin first. If the item is 25 cents and your wallet has 24 pennies and a quarter, the comments would have you turn over the entire contents of your wallet and get the pennies back in change, rather than just pay with the quarter.

Comment: apologies, I added the sample output and my output

Comment: What part do you need help with? The function you have asked for contains no code at all. The rest of your program is using functions you have not shown (buyItem). Not to mention that it is already a very long text dump. Please help us help you: reduce your code to the minimum required to get *your specific problem* and tell us what is going wrong.